# ASP.NET MVC File Upload and Download Full Site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, file-upload

Looking for a fully-featured ASP.NET 4.0 MVC site sample that acts as a simple "file area" to allow uploading and downloading exclusively over HTTP(s). WebForms 4.0 is cool also if there is nothing in the MVC world yet. I am looking to create a simple "FTP like" site and can't seem to find any good direction. All ideas appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try [aspupload.com](http://www.aspupload.com/)

I used aspupload's email brother (aspemail.com). Both are built by Persits Software.  It did what you expected, so recommend it on that basis.

Alternatively, you can try to get the free version of [Sitefinity](http://www.sitefinity.com) and use its Document Libraries that allow you to upload and manage files, although this might be overkill if you aren't up to speed with sitefinity.

Does .Net 4.0 not have an ftp api built in?

Comment: Thanks, but that component only handles the actual file transfer activity. I am interested in a full solution with GUI and file listing and etc. I have used mojoPortal in the past, cutting out all of the stuff except for the file transfer subsystem, but I was hoping there was something light out of the box with the same functionality.

Comment: Have a look at Sitefinity.  Might be more than you need, but learning to use it is not wasted time, as CMS is a growing area of web design.  It gives you the UI, etc, for file transfers.